# Xamarin iOS - Navigate to next text field with return key

Tags: ios, xamarin

I couldn't find anything in the Xamarin documentation about navigating to the next text field in a series of text fields on a form, only a small tutorial on removing the keyboard.

To keep things simple I am using a txtUsername(tag 1) text field and a txtPassword(tag 2) text field. When I implement the following code, it isn't transferring to Xamarin Studio. Does anyone know the way this can be done code in Xamarin Studio, or alternatively if I can transfer the code from XCode to Xamarin Studio.

I am using the following code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)txtUsername{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldReturn:");
    if (txtUsername.tag == 1) {
        UITextField *txtPassword= (UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:2];
        [txtPassword becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else {
        [txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of these functions

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIResponder.BecomeFirstResponder

```
BecomeFirstResponder()
```

and

http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIResponder.ResignFirstResponder

```
ResignFirstResponder()
```

According to the documentation you should add the textField Delegate method like this

```
public virtual bool ShouldReturn (UITextField textField)
{

   if (txtUsername.tag == 1) {

    UITextField txtPassword = (UITextField)this.view.ViewWithTag(2);

    txtPassword.BecomeFirstResponder();
   }
   else {
    txtUsername.ResignFirstResponder();
       }
return true;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't think to look in the API documentation, I looked in the Guides and Tutorials. If you can let me know how you get on that would be great, I'm new to Xamarin and XCode but I'll have a go at implementing them when I get home later.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've just tested this method and it works perfectly!

Comment: Any time @JonathanBick.

Comment: @satheeshwaran Hi I am having the same problem, and maybe I am missing something, where should the ShouldReturn delegate be? in XCODE or in my .xib code behind? I cant make this work... :(

Comment: http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UITextFieldDelegate.ShouldReturn

Comment: Figured it out late last night... been along time since I developed ios apps forgot all about those delegates :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Amit: Where did you put this function? Under the view controller constructor? Are `txtPassword` and `txtUsername` properties of the UIViewController? I don't get it working ...

Answer (score 7):

I think that the simplest way to do this is using the ShouldReturn method on your UITextFields with the BecomeFirstResponder method. For example, for a login form with Username and Password UITextFields, as follows (in your ViewDidLoad method):

```
Username = new UITextField();
Username.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Next;
Username.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress;
Username.ShouldReturn = (tf) =>
    {
        Password.BecomeFirstResponder();
        return true;
    };
View.Add(Username);

Password = new UITextField();
Password.SecureTextEntry = true;
Password.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Go;
Password.ShouldReturn = (tf) =>
    {
        // Do your login
        return true;
    };
View.Add(Password);
```

When you click next when the Username is active, it moves to the Password field. Clicking Go in the password field submits the form.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a generic solution for every form (not only those with 2 fields).

I´ve got a BaseViewController with these methods:

```
private UITextField[] formTextfields;
protected void EnableNextKeyForTextFields(UITextField[] fields)
    {
        formTextfields = fields;

        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            field.ShouldReturn += ShouldReturn;
        }
    }

    private bool ShouldReturn(UITextField textField)
    {
        int index = Array.IndexOf(formTextfields, textField);

        if (index > -1 && index < formTextfields.Length - 1)
        {
            formTextfields[index + 1].BecomeFirstResponder();
            return true;
        }
        else if (index == formTextfields.Length - 1)
        {
            formTextfields[index].ResignFirstResponder();
            FormFinished();
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected virtual void FormFinished()
    {
        // this should be implemented on viewControllers using "EnableNextKeyForTextFields"
    }
```

Then, in your view implementation, you just need to pass all your textfields in a single array:

```
EnableNextKeyForTextFields(new UITextField[] { NameField, SurnameField, EmailField, PasswordField });
```

When the users clicks "return" when editing the last field of the array, the method "FormFinished" will be called, so you can override it in your implementation:

```
protected override void FormFinished()
{
    (ViewModel as RegisterViewModel).Register(); // or whatever you need to do here
}
```

I hope this is useful for somebody

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample of how to implement in Xamarin.iOS. There may be other simpler ways to do this but I couldn't find any, and this works for me.

I subclassed UITextFieldDelegate to add a custom event handler, then created an instance of it in my view controller code, assigned a lambda expression to the custom event handler so I could access instance variables, and set this delegate instance as the Delegate on my 2 ext fields:

```
    public class LoginTextFieldDelegate : UITextFieldDelegate
    {
        public EventHandler<UITextField> OnShouldReturn;

        public override bool ShouldReturn(UITextField textField)
        {
            if (OnShouldReturn != null)
            {
                OnShouldReturn(this, textField);
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Then in my view controller ViewDidLoad method:

```
    var textDelegate = new LoginTextFieldDelegate
    {
        OnShouldReturn = (sender, textField) =>
        {
            if (textField.Tag == txtEmailAddress.Tag)
            {
                txtPassword.BecomeFirstResponder();
            }
            else if (textField.Tag == txtPassword.Tag)
            {
                txtPassword.ResignFirstResponder();
            }
        }
    };

    txtEmailAddress.Delegate = textDelegate;
    txtPassword.Delegate = textDelegate;
```

Don't forget to set a distinct tag on each UITextField in code / Interface Builder!

Answer (score 0):

Could be easier to use the class available [here](http://www.umarjamil.com/index.php/2015/07/16/navigating-through-uitextfields-with-the-ios-keyboard/)

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    // Manage keyboard and tab order
    new [] {
        usernameField, // Tab order = 0
        passwordField, // Tab order = 1
        emailField // Tab order = 2
    }.InitializeNavigationOnFields();
}
```

Just call the method passing all the text fields in the order you want them to be navigated through the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a solution on a Sign In Screen that handles the question in quite a simple and precise manner.

Not sure if these properties and events existed when the question was first asked but they will help out now for anyone else who needs it.

```
        Entry emailEntry = new Entry()
        {
            Keyboard = Keyboard.Email,
            ReturnType = ReturnType.Next //Changes Return Button on Keyboard to 'Next'
        };

        emailEntry.Completed += (s, e) => passwordEntry.Focus();
```

The Completed event fires when the Return Key is pressed. I then set the Focus to my passwordEntry field.

```
        Entry passwordEntry = new Entry()
        {
            IsPassword = true,
            ReturnType = ReturnType.Go //Changes Return Button on Keyboard to 'Next'
        }; 

        passwordEntry.Completed += (s, e) => SignInClick(s, e); //SignInClick method handles the sign in functionality
```

The Completed event for the password entry then initiates the SignInClick method which was previously only handled by a button on the screen.